# View(my.data) displays correct characters, print(my.data) is unreadable

Tags: r, encoding

Hej everyone, maybe someone can help me with the following (in my eyes) anomaly.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Chinese")
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("我", "你", "他") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)
View(df)
```

[image]

Whereas the output in the console looks odd:

```
print(df)
n    s    b
2    ÎÒ   TRUE
3    Äã   FALSE
5    Ëû   TRUE
```

I suppose this problem might also occur in other cases with non-standard encoding - anyone an idea what I can do? 
Best regards,
Steffi

PS:

> ```
> > sessionInfo()
> R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
> [3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 LC_NUMERIC=C                              
> [5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] bibliometrix_1.7 openxlsx_4.0.17  stringr_1.2.0    devtools_1.13.2  WriteXLS_4.0.0  
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>  [1] Rcpp_0.12.11         compiler_3.4.1       RColorBrewer_1.1-2   git2r_0.18.0         plyr_1.8.4          
>  [6] tools_3.4.1          digest_0.6.12        memoise_1.1.0        tibble_1.3.3         gtable_0.2.0        
> [11] lattice_0.20-35      rlang_0.1.1          Matrix_1.2-10        igraph_1.0.1         rstudioapi_0.6      
> [16] ggrepel_0.6.5        curl_2.7             parallel_3.4.1       factoextra_1.0.4     withr_1.0.2         
> [21] httr_1.2.1           cluster_2.0.6        rscopus_0.4.6        flashClust_1.01-2    grid_3.4.1          
> [26] scatterplot3d_0.3-40 R6_2.2.2             ggplot2_2.2.1        FactoMineR_1.36      magrittr_1.5        
> [31] scales_0.4.1         SnowballC_0.5.1      MASS_7.3-47          leaps_3.0            stringdist_0.9.4.4  
> [36] colorspace_1.3-2     stringi_1.1.5        lazyeval_0.2.0       munsell_0.4.3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

as the locale is already in Chinese, Try `data <- read.table("df", sep=','fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")` or `fileEncoding="UTF-8"`. See if it works

Comment: THanks for your answer. It unfortunately returns this error :Error: unexpected symbol in "data <- read.table("df", sep=',' fileEncoding"